# Canvas Drawing Application. Rotating Drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making canvas drawing application and I want to implement rotation of the drawing. But when I rotate it and want to keep drawing mouse cursor isn't pointing at the pixels which are being painted.
How can I fix that?
Here is my code:

```
    <button id="rotate">rotate right</button>



    var clickX = new Array();
    var clickY = new Array();
    var clickDrag = new Array();
    var paint = false;
    var context = null;
    var canvas = null;
    canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    rotate.onclick = function() { 

        context.translate(400,0);
        context.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);                 
        draw();
    }

    canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
        paint = true;           
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop,false);                    
        draw();

    }
    canvas.onmousemove = function(e){


    if(paint){  

        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);            
        draw();

        }
    canvas.onmouseup = function(){
      paint = false;
    }

   function addClick(x, y, dragging)
    { 


      clickX.push(x);
      clickY.push(y);
      clickDrag.push(dragging);       


    }

    function redraw(){
      context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
      context.lineJoin = "round";
      // usunieto context.lineWidth = 5;

      for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++)
      {     



        context.beginPath();
        if(clickDrag[i]){

          context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
         }else{
           context.moveTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
         }
         context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
         context.closePath();            
         context.stroke();
         }


      }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying an transformation to the canvas remains as the canvas state. You need to save the canvas state, apply the transformation, draw, then restore the canvas state. The 2D context API provides `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` to do this for you. It uses a stack to save the state so that means saves can be nested but each save must be removed with a matching restore;

```
ctx.save();  // push the current state onto the save stack
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2); // rotate 90deg clockwise
// call your draw function
ctx.restore();  // pop the last saved state from the save stack
```

That should fix you problem.

Comment: Using `.save` & `.restore` is overkill here -- the entire context state is saved and restored. Just do `ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);` to undo the rotation.

Comment: The `ctx.rotate` involves the creation of a complete matrix, and then a multiply. For speed just replace the existing matrix with the identity matrix `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` you can also get the current transform via `ctx.currentTransform` with properties `a, b, c, d, e, and f` representing the 3 vectors of the transform `a,b' x axis `c,d` y axis and `e,f` the origin.

Comment: Sure. No harm in resetting the entire transformation matrix in this simpler app. But remember that you are also blowing away all current transformations. In a more complex app, you might need to retain some of those other transformations by just reversing the local .rotate with `ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2)`.

Comment: The best approach is to leave the canvas state as is after the draw. In a complex app you are never sure what state will be required at the next draw so why restore a state that may not be needed.